# Facing "Index Not Found" intermittently in N1QL query

Tags: java, sdk, couchbase, sql++

Use Case: Searching "MAYUR" results come up in search but if I search "MAY" or "MA" no results.
I have implemented a search which search on startsWith("MAY%").
I am using couchbase versions 4.6.3-4136-E.

Error message is as follows:

> org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.CouchbaseQueryExecutionException:
>   Unable to execute query due to the following n1ql errors:
>   {"msg":"Index Not Found - cause: queryport.indexNotFound","code":12016}
>   {"msg":"Index Not Found - cause: queryport.indexNotFound","code":12016}
>   {"msg":"Index Not Found - cause: queryport.indexNotFound","code":12016}
>   {"msg":"Index Not Found - cause: queryport.indexNotFound","code":12016}

Java SDK version : 2.5.5

I am facing this issue intermittently.

Code to run the query

```
public <T> PageImpl<T> runQuery(final Statement statement, final Expression expression, final String alias,
        final Pageable pageable, final Class<T> tClazz) {
    PageImpl<T> tPage = null;
    try {
        CompletableFuture<List<T>> entityFuture = CompletableFuture
                .supplyAsync(() -> findByN1QLProjection(statement, tClazz)).exceptionally(th -> {
                    logger.write(new Exception(th.getMessage(), th));
                    return Collections.emptyList();
                });
        CompletableFuture<Long> countFuture = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> doCount(expression, alias))
                .exceptionally(th -> {
                    logger.write(new Exception(th.getMessage(), th));
                    return 0L;
                });
        CompletableFuture.allOf(entityFuture, countFuture).get();
        tPage = new PageImpl<>(entityFuture.get(), pageable, countFuture.get());
    } catch (final InterruptedException | ExecutionException ex) {
        logger.write(ex);
        tPage = new PageImpl<>(Collections.emptyList(), pageable, 0);
    }
    return tPage;
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? You need to provide more detail and information if you want someone to help you debug your code.

Comment: @divibisan what other information do you need?

Comment: I can't say since I don't know java or couchbase, but I know from experience that the more clear your question is and the more context you provide the more likely you are to get a helpful answer.

Comment: What index(es) have you created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**RootCause:** 
Faulty execution plan was cached by the query service and subsequently used and because of index-id unavailability (as indexes were recreated), the query kept throwing error: 'Index not found'.

**Resolution:** 
After cleaning the stored prepared plans, query started working.

Comment: how to clean it? @ThatMan